# Connection refused with self-compiled Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-build

I downloaded and compiled the Android 4.1 sources (with full-eng configuration). I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox. However, when I try to run the emulator, I only get a black screen on the emulated device. There seems to be problem with network connection between emulator and emulated device, shown by the  error at the end of the log. I attached the output of  `emulator -debug all` below. Any help as to what's causing the connection problem or otherwise how to get the emulator to run properly would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Log:

```
emulator: autoconfig: -datadir out/target/product/generic/
emulator: Found target ABI=armeabi-v7a, architecture=arm
emulator: Found target API level: 15
emulator: using core hw config path: out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: no skin-specific hardware.ini in (null)
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to HOME
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to ESCAPE
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PAGEUP
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PAGEDOWN
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to KEYPAD_PLUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to KEYPAD_MINUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to Alt-ENTER
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to KEYPAD_8
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to KEYPAD_4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to KEYPAD_6
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to KEYPAD_2
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to DELETE
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to KEYPAD_7
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to KEYPAD_9
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to KEYPAD_DIVIDE
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/tobi/.android/default.keyset
emulator: /home/tobi/.android/emulator-user.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='window.x' VALUE='464'
emulator:    2: KEY='window.y' VALUE='153'
emulator:    3: KEY='uuid' VALUE='1343139837397'
emulator: /home/tobi/.android/emulator-user.ini: parsing finished
emulator: skin name 'HVGA' aliased to '320x480'
emulator: found magic skin width=320 height=480 bpp=16

emulator: Using initial system image: out/target/product/generic/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata out/target/product/generic//userdata.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

emulator: Found target ABI=armeabi-v7a
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu cortex-a8
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing as .ini file
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing finished
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 320
  hw.lcd.height = 480
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = out/target/product/generic/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 1g
  disk.dataPartition.path = out/target/product/generic//out/target/product/generic/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 1g
  avd.name = <build>
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator64-arm -android-hw out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service hw-control
emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
emulator: out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='arm'
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.cpu.model' VALUE='cortex-a8'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='512'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.screen' VALUE='touch'
emulator:    5: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    7: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='no'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.keyboard.lid' VALUE='no'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='qwerty2'
emulator:   10: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   11: KEY='hw.gsmModem' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   12: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   13: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   14: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   15: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   16: KEY='hw.audioOutput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   17: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   18: KEY='hw.sdCard.path' VALUE='sdcard.img'
emulator:   19: KEY='disk.cachePartition' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   20: KEY='disk.cachePartition.size' VALUE='66m'
emulator:   21: KEY='hw.lcd.width' VALUE='320'
emulator:   22: KEY='hw.lcd.height' VALUE='480'
emulator:   23: KEY='hw.lcd.depth' VALUE='16'
emulator:   24: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='160'
emulator:   25: KEY='hw.lcd.backlight' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   26: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='no'
emulator:   27: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='emulated'
emulator:   28: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
emulator:   29: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='48'
emulator:   30: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   31: KEY='hw.sensors.magnetic_field' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   32: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   33: KEY='hw.sensors.temperature' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   34: KEY='kernel.path' VALUE='prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu'
emulator:   35: KEY='kernel.parameters' VALUE='android.checkjni=1'
emulator:   36: KEY='disk.ramdisk.path' VALUE='out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img'
emulator:   37: KEY='disk.systemPartition.initPath' VALUE='out/target/product/generic/system.img'
emulator:   38: KEY='disk.systemPartition.size' VALUE='1g'
emulator:   39: KEY='disk.dataPartition.path' VALUE='out/target/product/generic//out/target/product/generic/userdata.img'
emulator:   40: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='1g'
emulator:   41: KEY='avd.name' VALUE='<build>'
emulator: out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini: parsing finished
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x40000000,initfile=out/target/product/generic/system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-b5DFo1
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 40008000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x40000000
emulator: mapping 'userdata' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-Jya97P
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 40008000

emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gsm
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gps
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service camera
emulator: android_camera_service_init: Registered 'camera' qemud service
emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 127.0.0.1
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000
emulator: mapping 'cache' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-xvZxgQ
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: Can't start OpenGLES renderer?
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: qpa_audio_init: entering
emulator: qpa_audio_init: exiting
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service sensors
emulator: android_hw_sensors_init: sensors qemud service initialized
emulator: Found ro.adb.qemud build property: 1
emulator: ADB server has been initialized for port 5555. Socket: 23
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service adb
emulator: android_adb_service_init: Registered 'adb' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service adb-debug
emulator: Registered 'adb-debug' qemud service
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Connection refused
emulator: ping program: /media/Android/jellybean/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ddms
emulator: ping command: /media/Android/jellybean/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ddms ping emulator 20.0 "" "" ""
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 22
emulator: User-config was not changed.
emulator: autoconfig: -datadir out/target/product/generic/
emulator: Found target ABI=armeabi-v7a, architecture=arm
emulator: Found target API level: 15
emulator: using core hw config path: out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/generic//development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA
emulator: Probing skin directory: out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator:     ignore bad skin directory out/target/product/skins/HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: no skin-specific hardware.ini in (null)
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to HOME
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to ESCAPE
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PAGEUP
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PAGEDOWN
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to KEYPAD_PLUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to KEYPAD_MINUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to Alt-ENTER
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to KEYPAD_8
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to KEYPAD_4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to KEYPAD_6
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to KEYPAD_2
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to DELETE
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to KEYPAD_7
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to KEYPAD_9
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to KEYPAD_DIVIDE
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/tobi/.android/default.keyset
emulator: /home/tobi/.android/emulator-user.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='window.x' VALUE='464'
emulator:    2: KEY='window.y' VALUE='153'
emulator:    3: KEY='uuid' VALUE='1343139837397'
emulator: /home/tobi/.android/emulator-user.ini: parsing finished
emulator: skin name 'HVGA' aliased to '320x480'
emulator: found magic skin width=320 height=480 bpp=16

emulator: Using initial system image: out/target/product/generic/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata out/target/product/generic//userdata.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

emulator: Found target ABI=armeabi-v7a
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu cortex-a8
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing as .ini file
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing finished
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 320
  hw.lcd.height = 480
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = out/target/product/generic/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 1g
  disk.dataPartition.path = out/target/product/generic//out/target/product/generic/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 1g
  avd.name = <build>
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator64-arm -android-hw out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service hw-control
emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
emulator: out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='arm'
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.cpu.model' VALUE='cortex-a8'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='512'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.screen' VALUE='touch'
emulator:    5: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    7: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='no'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.keyboard.lid' VALUE='no'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='qwerty2'
emulator:   10: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   11: KEY='hw.gsmModem' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   12: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   13: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   14: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   15: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   16: KEY='hw.audioOutput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   17: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   18: KEY='hw.sdCard.path' VALUE='sdcard.img'
emulator:   19: KEY='disk.cachePartition' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   20: KEY='disk.cachePartition.size' VALUE='66m'
emulator:   21: KEY='hw.lcd.width' VALUE='320'
emulator:   22: KEY='hw.lcd.height' VALUE='480'
emulator:   23: KEY='hw.lcd.depth' VALUE='16'
emulator:   24: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='160'
emulator:   25: KEY='hw.lcd.backlight' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   26: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='no'
emulator:   27: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='emulated'
emulator:   28: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
emulator:   29: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='48'
emulator:   30: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   31: KEY='hw.sensors.magnetic_field' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   32: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   33: KEY='hw.sensors.temperature' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   34: KEY='kernel.path' VALUE='prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu'
emulator:   35: KEY='kernel.parameters' VALUE='android.checkjni=1'
emulator:   36: KEY='disk.ramdisk.path' VALUE='out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img'
emulator:   37: KEY='disk.systemPartition.initPath' VALUE='out/target/product/generic/system.img'
emulator:   38: KEY='disk.systemPartition.size' VALUE='1g'
emulator:   39: KEY='disk.dataPartition.path' VALUE='out/target/product/generic//out/target/product/generic/userdata.img'
emulator:   40: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='1g'
emulator:   41: KEY='avd.name' VALUE='<build>'
emulator: out/target/product/generic//hardware-qemu.ini: parsing finished
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x40000000,initfile=out/target/product/generic/system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-UZrNgA
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 40008000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x40000000
emulator: mapping 'userdata' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-4zxtnk
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 40008000

emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gsm
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gps
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service camera
emulator: android_camera_service_init: Registered 'camera' qemud service
emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 127.0.0.1
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000
emulator: mapping 'cache' NAND image to /tmp/android-tobi/emulator-g1kmDf
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: Can't start OpenGLES renderer?
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: qpa_audio_init: entering
emulator: qpa_audio_init: exiting
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service sensors
emulator: android_hw_sensors_init: sensors qemud service initialized
emulator: Found ro.adb.qemud build property: 1
emulator: ADB server has been initialized for port 5555. Socket: 23
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service adb
emulator: android_adb_service_init: Registered 'adb' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service adb-debug
emulator: Registered 'adb-debug' qemud service
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Connection refused
emulator: ping program: /media/Android/jellybean/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ddms
emulator: ping command: /media/Android/jellybean/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ddms ping emulator 20.0 "" "" ""
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 22
emulator: could not handle (sym=306, mod=0, str=(null))
emulator: User-config was not changed.
```

Comment: I think this has more to do with OpenGles renderer than network connection. Have you  tried adding **`-gpu on`**  to the emulator option?

Comment: Tried that now, and it didn't make a difference. Would have surprised me anyways because if there is a problem with the OpenGLES-renderer the more sensible thing to me seems to be to turn it off, not on. And after all, that's only a warning in the log, not an error like the refused connection.

Answer (score 0):

almost with the same config : full-eng generic -4.1.2  arm
I got it work under emulator-arm

Please see many screenshots, liveusb_image ,live_iso_image allowing emulating cyanogenmod
even in ubuntu-12.04

https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/Android-CyanogenMod/